# Stuck on IOS authentication Intune

Tags: ios, swift, adal, intune

Some devices, apparently enrolled correctly on Microsoft Intune, by the company where I work, are receiving the following error after authentication via Microsoft Authenticator:

> canOpenURL: failed for URL: "msauth://broker" - error: "The operation
> couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

The app is using:
iOS 15.0,
ADAL SDK integrated manually (no cocoapods)

Many thanks for any support!

Comment: reinstall ADAL library. It will install latest version ADAL SDK and try to run again. 
Check this : https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following. Based on the error it seems ios 15.0 version is not supported with old version of ADAL (ie MSAL).

We recommend remaining up-to-date with the latest version of ADAL. The best place to check what the most recent version is the [releases page](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc/releases) on GitHub, or a tool that relies on that data. Tools like [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/) can make it easier to set up your project dependencies and update to the latest release.

**Note** :

1. To work with iOS 15, you must have at least version 5.0.0. However, we recommend switching to version 6.0.0 since 5.0.0 won't be maintained.
2. To work with iOS 13+ (when built with Xcode 11) you must have at least version 2.7.14 or 4.0.2

Please follow this [document](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc) you to have multiple options to use MSAL library in your iOS project: